# Passing Multiples Values from Listbox or DropDownList from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view with a form with Get method .

I m trying to pass 2 selected values from my listbox **Proyecto** in my view

**View** 
[image]

This is my code of the action result

[image]

the console printme only 1 value

[image]

and the filter works only for this value.

and in the url is passing 2 values

[image]

thanks, and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the parameter in your action to take an array of strings:

```
public ActionResult FiscalYearDup (string[] ProjectList=null,...
```